# SQL query with distinct and sum

Tags: sql, sum, distinct, ansi-sql

I have the following `medleys` table that combines `colors`, `fruits` and `ratings`:

```
[medleys]
medley_id   |   color   |   fruit   |   rating
==============================================
1               red         apple       25
2               blue        pear        5
3               green       apple       12
4               red         apple       10
5               purple      kiwi        5
6               purple      kiwi        50
7               blue        kiwi        3
8               blue        pear        9
```

I am trying to write an ANSI-compliant SQL query that will combine every unique/distinct `color`-`fruit` pair and sum each pair's individual `rating` values.  Thus if you ran the query on the table above it would produce the following result sets:

```
[query]
color   |   fruit   |   sum
===========================
red         apple       35
blue        pear        14
blue        kiwi        3
green       apple       12
purple      kiwi        55
```

Thus, the query sees there are two `red`-`apple` pairs in the table, and so it creates one result for the `red`-`apple` pair, and adds up their constituent `ratings` (25 + 10 = 35), etc.

I am sure that I need to do a select for **distinct** color/fruit values, but not sure how to aggregate the ratings at the same "level/scope":

```
SELECT
    distinct(color, fruit), sum(rating)
FROM
    medleys
```

Order doesn't matter. `color` and `fruit` are VARCHAR(50)s and `rating` is INT. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
SELECT color, fruit, sum(rating)
FROM medleys
GROUP BY color, fruit
```

Distinct is used to select distinct elements, nothing more, while you want to aggregate and for that you need `GROUP BY` and aggregation functions (`SUM`).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `distinct` at all.  You need `group by`:

```
select color, fruit, sum(rating)
from medleys
group by color, fruit
```

I'm answering, because I see this mistake occur.  In general, you don't need `select distinct` at all in SQL.  You can always use a `group by` instead.  `Distinct` should be introduced after `group by` as a convenient short-hand.

Comment: And what if you wanted to know all the unique colors of fruits, or maybe all the unique fruits you have in your table? Would you use `DISTINCT` then?

Comment: You *could*, but the point is that you could also replace it with `GROUP BY` - aggregation is the overall concept that needs to be understood.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `color`,`fruit`,SUM(`rating`)
FROM Medleys
GROUP BY `color`,`fruit`
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b238c7/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question:

```
SELECT color, fruit, sum(rating) as [sum]
FROM medleys
GROUP BY color, fruit
ORDER BY color
```