# How to combine SELECT DISTINCT and SUM()

Tags: sql, select

I have a table like given bellow, in Oracle:

```
[Products]
Product_ID | Product_NME | Product_SUP | Quantity
=================================================
    1         Apple         USA           100
    2         Fish          Japan          50
    3         Wine          Italy          10
    4         Apple         China          30
    5         Fish          Germany        10
```

I need a query that will find the full `Quantity` for every `Product_NME` by `DISTINCT`.

The expected result should be:

- apple 130
- fish 60
- wine 10

I've tried to modify it like the one [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512628/sql-query-with-distinct-and-sum) as:

```
SELECT
    distinct(Product_NME, Product_SUP), sum(Quantity)
FROM
    Products
```

But it's not my case. Also I've tried this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Product_NME
FROM Products 
UNION
SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Products
```

But is also not working.

Can anyone help me with this?

- Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What is the expected result? E.g. do you want "Apple 100" or "Apple 30" or "Apple 130"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is not the clause you are looking for!

`GROUP BY` is.

The following query will return with all products and the total quantity for each one.

```
SELECT
  Product_NME
  , SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
FROM
  Products 
GROUP BY
  Product_NME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Product_NME, SUM(Quantity) FROM Products GROUP BY Product_NME
```

Comment: Don't just post code an answer, add a brief explanation for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need for distinct just group by product name :

```
SELECT  Product_NME , SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQTY 

FROM  Products 

GROUP BY Product_NME
```