# Similliar aggregate function to unique/distinct in R Postgres Backend

Tags: r, tidyverse, dbplyr, rpostgresql

How does it work to aggregate a variable in a postgres db backend table to its unique value. For example i have the following table:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)

dbplyr::memdb_frame(a=c(2,2,2), b=c(2,3,4)) %>%
summarise(aggregatedSum = sum(b), 
          aggregatedUnique = unique(a))
```

But neither `unique()` nor `distinct()` are doing the job. Any ideas how to achieve my desired outcome like so when i collect() the table before summarise:

```
dbplyr::memdb_frame(a=c(2,2,2), b=c(2,3,4)) %>%
collect() %>%
summarise(aggregatedSum = sum(b), 
          aggregatedUnique = unique(a))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  aggregatedSum aggregatedUnique
          <dbl>            <dbl>
1             9                2
```

Comment: Does column `a` in your database always only contain one distinct value? Or do you have several distinct values in column `a` and you want a row for each one in your output?

Comment: it always contains one distinct value

Comment: but your second point is also interesting

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25758554/3358272

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a `group_by` to your `dplyr` pipe:

```
> dbplyr::memdb_frame(a=c(2,2,2), b=c(2,3,4)) %>%
+   group_by(a) %>% 
+   summarise(aggregatedSum = sum(b)) %>% 
+   rename(aggregatedUnique = a) %>% 
+   select(aggregatedSum, aggregatedUnique)

# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: sqlite 3.34.1 [:memory:]
  aggregatedSum aggregatedUnique
          <dbl>            <dbl>
1             9                2
```

If there are multiple distinct values in column `a`, this will return a row per value (with the sum of the `b` values that occur alongside them).

Comment: `group_by()` would be a possibility, but I always try to avoid it because it is more computationally intensive. But unfortunately it seems there are no unique/distinct alike functions. I'll will then just use another aggregate function like max()/min()/mean() for such cases, since every value in `a` is equal anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misinterpreting, but this seems like a grouping operation, where you might want the sum of `b` for each unique value of `a`. If so, then `group_by(a)`:

```r
dbplyr::memdb_frame(a=c(2,2,2), b=c(2,3,4)) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(aggregatedSum = sum(b))
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# # Database: sqlite 3.33.0 [:memory:]
#       a aggregatedSum
#   <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1     2             9
```

This is related to [How to combine SELECT DISTINCT and SUM()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25758554/3358272) in that I believe SQL does not let you `sum(.)` and `distinct(.)` in the same query. The unchanged query looks like:

```r
dbplyr::memdb_frame(a=c(2,2,2), b=c(2,3,4)) %>%
  summarise(aggregatedSum = sum(b), 
          aggregatedUnique = distinct(a)) %>%
  show_query()
# <SQL>
# SELECT SUM(`b`) AS `aggregatedSum`, distinct(`a`) AS `aggregatedUnique`
# FROM `dbplyr_014`
```

whereas the updated query is

```r
dbplyr::memdb_frame(a=c(2,2,2), b=c(2,3,4)) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(aggregatedSum = sum(b)) %>%
  show_query()
# <SQL>
# SELECT `a`, SUM(`b`) AS `aggregatedSum`
# FROM `dbplyr_016`
# GROUP BY `a`
```

which is aligned with the linked question/answer.

Comment: `group_by()` would be a possibility, but I always try to avoid it because it is more computationally intensive. But unfortunately it seems there are no unique/distinct alike functions. I'll will then just use another aggregate function like max()/min()/mean() for such cases, since every value in `a` is equal anyway.

Comment: The data-viewpoint here is confusing to me. I suspect that it is overly-simplified for the sake of a question on SO, where the variability of the larger real data is unknown to us. Good luck.