# How to Populate CollectionView with Sql Query with combination of Distinct, Sum and Count .... in Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, collectionview

**SQL QUERY SAMPLE**

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(con.dBasePath))
                {
                    SalesRecords.ItemsSource = conn.Query<DATA_BINDING.PURCHASED_PRODUCTS> 
                    ("SELECT DISTINCT([soldProduct]), (SUM ([soldAmount])) FROM 
                    [PURCHASED_PRODUCTS] " +
                    "WHERE salesDate BETWEEN '" + btnDateFrom.Date.ToString("dd MMM yy") 
                    + "' AND '" + btnDateTo.Date.ToString("dd MMM yy") + "'");

                }]
```

**.....XAMARIN CODE.....**

```
     <Label **Text="{Binding soldProduct}"** HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="8,0,0,0" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"></Label>


<Label **Text="{Binding soldAmount}"** TextColor="#2ABD8F" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="22" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                           LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Margin="0,-11,0,0"></Label>
```

**Please how can i make this possible, with the distinct and sum at same time**

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(con.dBasePath))
                {
                    SalesRecords.ItemsSource = conn.Query<DATA_BINDING.PURCHASED_PRODUCTS> 
                    ("SELECT DISTINCT([soldProduct]) FROM 
                    [PURCHASED_PRODUCTS] " +
                    "WHERE salesDate BETWEEN '" + btnDateFrom.Date.ToString("dd MMM yy") 
                    + "' AND '" + btnDateTo.Date.ToString("dd MMM yy") + "'");
                }   THIS CODE WORKS WITHOUT THE SUM([SOLDAMOUNT]), BUT I WANT TO POPULATE THE COLLECTIONVIEW WITH DISTINCT AND SUM AT SAMETIME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`.

`DISTINCT` is used to select distinct elements , nothing more . If you want to aggregate(`SUM`) the items you need to use `GROUP BY`.

```
"SELECT soldProduct, (SUM ([soldAmount])) FROM [PURCHASED_PRODUCTS] " +
 "WHERE salesDate BETWEEN '" + btnDateFrom.Date.ToString("dd MMM yy") 
+ "' AND '" + btnDateTo.Date.ToString("dd MMM yy") + "'" + "GROUP BY soldProduct"
```

Refer to

[How to combine SELECT DISTINCT and SUM()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758554/how-to-combine-select-distinct-and-sum/25758699)

[SQL query with distinct and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512628/sql-query-with-distinct-and-sum)

Comment: thank you very much, it work well following your process

 SalesRecords.ItemsSource = conn.Query<DATA_BINDING.DataAnalysis>("SELECT soldProduct, COUNT(soldProduct) AS count, " +
                        "SUM(soldAmount) AS total FROM [PURCHASED_PRODUCTS] " +
                        "WHERE salesDate BETWEEN '" + datFROM + "' AND '" + datTO + "' GROUP BY soldProduct");