# SUM AND distinct in linq

Tags: sql, asp.net

I want to run the below SQL query in linq using a datatable

```
select 
      SUM(cast(Percentage as int))
     ,Subject 
from tablename 
where Student_ID = xxx 
group by Subject_ID
```

How can I do it? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Aggregate-Operators-c51b3869#SumGrouped

Comment: Please refer to [here][1] I hope this helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512628/sql-query-with-distinct-and-sum

Comment: i have tried this ds1.Tables[i].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("Percentage")).Select(group => group.First()).CopyToDataTable();

Answer (score 1):

Use `Enumerable.GroupBy`, `Sum` and an anonymous type to store the result:

```
var query =  tablename.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<int>("Student_ID") == xxx)
    .GroupBy(row => new { SubjectID = row.Field<int>("Subject_ID"), Subject = row.Field<string>("Subject") })
    .Select(g => new 
    { 
        SumPercentage = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Percentage")),
        Subject = g.Key.Subject, SubjectID = g.Key.SubjectID
    });
```

I don't know why you need to cast `Percentage` to `int`, but i'm pretty sure that you get it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,and because the field is varchar so convert to int

Comment: @dazzlingkumar: then you just have to use `g.Sum(r => int.Parse(r.Field<string>("Percentage")))`. But why don't you store int in the first place?