# Displaying unique values in loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have in my database a table of product requests.

[image: Datas]

I am now making a summary of user's request. Which displays all the user's request without duplicating the product names (should be unique), and get the total quantity and amount.

This is my code and what I have tried so far. I tried using unique array.

```
$all_product_name = array();

foreach ( $rows as $row ) {

    $all_product_name[] = $row;
    $allproduct = array_unique( $all_product_name );
}

 foreach ($allproduct as $product) { 

    print_r($product);

 }
```

This gives me all the products and not the unique product names.

What I would like to do is to is to show only unique product names, and the sum of the quantity and amount of all products.

[image]

I am stuck, any help and ideas?

Comment: You could just issue a query for that.

Comment: Using `DISTINCT`? But when I use it, Could I get the total amount of the product?

Comment: There's also a `SUM()` function. Try checking out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512649/3244407 It makes use of `SUM` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: Use a query, like in mysql it would be -
    select sum(prod_quantity), sum(prod_amount) group by prod_name

Solution 2: Iterate over the rows to create associative array of prod_name

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $prod_name = $row['prod_name'];
    $prod[$prod_name]['amount'] = $prod[$prod_name]['amount'] + $row['prod_amount'];
    $prod[$prod_name]['quantity'] = $prod[$prod_name]['quantity'] + $row['prod_quantity'];
}
```

Output will be like:

```
Array
(
    [Product1] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 2600 //sum of prod_amount
        [quantity] => 6  //sum of prod_quantity
    )

[Product2] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 6600
        [quantity] => 5
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Very specific answer. Tried Sol#2. Cheers!